# What is the proper convention for binding the context of many React component methods in constructor()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a lot of methods in my top-level React component that I want to use as callbacks in its children components. I understand that in ES6 I must manually bind the context of each method. My current constructor method looks something like this:

```
this.method1 = this.method1.bind(this);
this.method2 = this.method2.bind(this);
this.method3 = this.method3.bind(this);
...
```

This works; all of my children are able to retain the intended context whenever they invoke their callbacks but it seems like a lot of code to write for something I did not even need to write in ES5. Is there a quick way to bind context to all of my component methods without having to write all of this boilerplate?

Comment: I suggest you look at my answer, even though @naomik downvoted and flagged for deletion. It is the solution directly from Facebook, with explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that in ES6 I must manually bind the context of each method.

Yeah, except that's not entirely true. ES6 allows you to express things a lot better than you could in ES5.

Writing your code in ES6 doesn't mean you directly translate the code you have from ES5. There's more idiomatic ways to do it using new features  in current versions of React and features that are native to ES6.

```
import {Component} from 'react'

class Foo extends Component {
  // this class doesn't even need constructor

  createButton(text) {
    // don't write
    // return <button onclick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{text}</button>
    // instead write
    return <button onclick={e=> this.handleClick(e)}>{text}</button>
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    console.log(event, 'button was clicked')
  }

  render() {
    var {buttons} = this.props;
    // don't write
    // return <div>{buttons.map(this.createButton.bind(this)}</div>
    // instead write
    return <div>{buttons.map(this.createButton, this)}</div>
  }
}

export default Foo;

// <Foo buttons={["one", "two", "three"]} />
```

Notice I used context in two different ways that didn't require `Function.prototype.bind`

1. **Arrow functions** have a lexical `this` therefore a binding isn't required in most scenarios. Arrow functions are new to ES6.
2. **`Array.prototype` functions** like `map`,`reduce`,`forEach` accept a `thisArgument` which allows you to change the context of the callback. This is not new to ES6, so there's nothing stopping you from using this in your ES5 code today.

---

But do you also see this is a [stateless functional component](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components)? Stateless functional components are available as of **React 0.14**

> In idiomatic React code, most of the components you write will be stateless, simply composing other components. We’re introducing a new, simpler syntax for these components where you can take props as an argument and return the element you want to render
>
> <sub>*source: [React Blog v0.14](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components)*</sub>

This code is functionally identical to the component above but requires no `class` or context ceremony

```
const createButton = (text) => {
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{text}</button>
}

const handleClick = (event) => {
  console.log(event, 'button was clicked')
}

// stateless functional component
const Foo = ({buttons}) => {
  return <div>{buttons.map(createButton)}</div>
}

export default Foo;
```

Of course this approach cannot work for components that involve `state` (or life cycle methods), but it works for any Components that just use `props` - which is most of your components.

It's just one more technique you have to write React apps in an idiomatic way that doesn't involve `Function.prototype.bind`.

For what it's worth, I haven't relied upon `Function.prototype.bind` (with code I've written) in years.

Comment: Your proposed solutions with arrow functions and the array prototype functions involve binding multiple times. React / Facebook do NOT recommend this. [From there documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes): "We recommend that you bind your event handlers in the constructor so they are only bound once for every instance. This is better for performance of your application, especially if you implement shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow comparison in the child components."

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Babel, you can enable stage 0 and use the `::` this binding operator.

You should be able to bind to the parent context when passing to the children:

```
method1() {
  ...
}

render() {
  return <ChildComponent method1={::this.method1} />;
}
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/
http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/

Comment: I believe this means you are binding the method every time ``render`` is called, which is bad practice.

Comment: Causes performance issues? I think his objective could also be achieved with arrow functions as class properties.

Answer (score -1):

There are various valid approaches here; the one I prefer is to use the `@autobind` decorator:

```
import autobind from 'autobind-decorator';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    @autobind
    method1() {
        // "this" is bound correctly
    }
}
```

This requires the [autobind-decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobind-decorator) module (or [core-decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-decorators), which exposes a similar function), plus [babel-preset-decorators-legacy](https://github.com/kt3k/babel-preset-decorators-legacy).

Comment: You should definitely mention that the decorator module only exists for people to make an easy transition from babel 5 to babel 6 and that decorators are currently not part of the spec.

Comment: @naomik - if you use the `decorators-legacy` preset, that's moot - it'll still work as Babel and ES7 evolve. When the spec is ironed out, presumably the decorator packages will update to support the new API.